# how to send data rapidly between a service and an activty

Tags: android, class, service, android-asynctask, download

how can i send data from a service to an activity if that activity is running without restarting service or activity. actually i have a Asynctask class inside my service that downloads a file and i wanna show the percentage of downloading on a Progress-bar inside an activity . can any one tell me how should i do that?
i tried interface in asynctask but it make a new request and my progress bar is null.

```
public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Combine,String,Combine> {
Responcer1 responder;
HttpURLConnection connection;
int id;
int position;


public Downloader(int position){
    this.position=position;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    responder=new SavedLinks();
    responder.start(position);
}

@Override
protected Combine doInBackground(Combine... param) {

    try {
        int position=param[0].position;
        Log.i("downloader",param[0].caption+param[0].link+param[0].url+param[0].user);
        id=param[0].id;

        connection = null;
        URL url;
        url = new URL(param[0].link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(45000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");}
        in.close();
        connection.disconnect();
        return saperate(sb.toString(),param[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), a library written just to simplify interaction between activity, service and so on. It's quite simple to use, you can start reading [quick start guide](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need to actually send it all that frequently.  Every couple of seconds is good enough for a progress bar.  But ignoring that, there's a couple of good solutions:

1)Broadcast the status from the Service and use a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity

2)Bind to the service and pass in a status callback to the Service to call back to your activity

3)Use an EventBus for message passing of status

2 and 3 require the service to be in the same process, but since that's the default they're probably ok.